# Dynamically Limit Number of Connection per Request using PHP only

Tags: php, concurrency, python-requests, connection, limit

I am trying to server downloads dynamically using PHP.

I want to limit the number of threads or segmented downloading.

So basically if the users wants to make 4 threads open to a same download link then its okay.

Now if he wants to download using 6 thread the extra 2 request will give him access denied using proper http code in error.

Now you can achieve this functionality using php mod_qos and other but I don't want this value fixed.

All users will be connected to a mysql database and basically depending upon the whole load the server will dynamically allocate resources to user.

Working Environment Laravel 5.7+.

VPS with full root access.

Comment: _using PHP_ So why the `Python_request` tag

Comment: It was edited by riggs folly 

I didnt see that he changed the tag